# Set timeout for JDBC requests in JMeter?

Tags: jdbc, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-5.0

Is it possible to set timeout for JDBC request in JMeter? I understand that the Sample Timeout can only be used with a handful of requests, but not JDBC ([see here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Sample_Timeout)). Is there a workaround? I'm using JMeter 5.0. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Set [Max wait](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Connection_Configuration) of the JDBC Connection configuration to simulate connection timeout of its JDBC Requests

> Max Wait (ms)
>   Pool throws an error if the timeout period is exceeded in the process of trying to retrieve a connection, s

Comment: Thanks. If retrieving a connection is fast but querying takes time, does it abort and throw error? It does not seem to work for me.